Pinescript and Binance
I read about the announcement of a collaboration with Binance in 2023. After connecting the broker and being able to manually trade, I am wondering if trading functionalities are available using Pinescript as well.
Can I now send trading signals directly to Binance using Pinescript? Or shall I still use third party services as Capitalise using webhooks?
I am asking because no ones talk about it on this website, tradingview or on the Web.
Thank you
There is no mentioning of this around

You cannot execute trades directly via Pinescript. You still need to use webhooks.
If you are a USDⓈ-M Futures user, you can directly setup this webhook via Binance. See this. Otherwise, you will need a 3rd party service such as Capitalise, 3Commas etc.
